An element of order p in $S_p$ is a p-cycle and there is no element of order kp for $k \geq 2$
Apologize if it is elementary but here goes.
I think I am already convinced of the first part of the statement since that this element would generate a subgroup with p elements  and would be cyclic.
But I am still not sure of how to proceed to the part of showing that there is no element of order kp for $k \geq 2$ can someone help me? What should I use?
(I am aware of things like cauchy, sylow mas Lagrange's theorem)

Do you know that the order of a permutation is the least common multiple of the cycle lenghts if the permutation is written as a product of disjoint cycles?

This post might be far more useful to other users in the future if it included an explicitly and clearly stated question. Neither its title nor its body does so. Was it your intention that the title constitute the statement of a particular claim that you were trying to prove? For example, where you wrote and, did you mean then?

Suppose there exists an element $\sigma$ of order $kp$ in $S_p$ for $k\ge 2$.  What would that mean?
Well, since $p$ is prime, we need a cycle $\pi$ of length $p$ such that $\sigma=\tau\pi$ for some $\tau$. (Why?)
But now we have exhausted the support set (i.e., the set of cardinality $p$ that $S_p$ acts on by definition) using $\pi$.
Can you complete the proof from here?

If such $\tau$ existed it would not be disjoint from $\pi$. Thus a contradiction.

Exactly, @VictorHugo. Well done!
